# Spring Boot doesn't seem to find Repository

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm not sure what's wrong with my configuration, but as far as I can see it should be correct, despite that spring announces that there is no such bean definition. I veryfied these points:

- The configuration class is in the root package of everything else
- The repository extends JpaRepository, thus needs no annotation
- The player object is annotated with "@Entity"
- The pojo for this repository is completely mapped in terms of annotations
- No non-java configuration files present
- The database is set up and the correct credentials are used.
- Jpa/hibernate is set to "Create-Update" for development purposes.

Here's my complete debug log:
[spring startup log pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MDT5nQ6s)

log without debug flag:

```
2017-06-12 09:34:36.395  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] 
d.a.c.newworlds.NewWorldsApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-12 09:34:36.727  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10057b9b: startup date [Mon Jun 12 09:34:36 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-12 09:34:38.090  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'playerRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-06-12 09:34:38.107  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'userAccountRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-06-12 09:34:38.115  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'organizationRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-06-12 09:34:38.612  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-12 09:34:38.664  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-12 09:34:38.701  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93eeb181] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-12 09:34:39.009  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-12 09:34:39.019  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-12 09:34:39.020  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-06-12 09:34:39.243  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-12 09:34:39.243  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2521 ms
2017-06-12 09:34:39.635  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 09:34:39.635  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 09:34:39.636  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 09:34:39.636  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 09:34:39.637  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 09:34:39.637  INFO 12880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-12 09:34:40.130  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-12 09:34:40.156  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2017-06-12 09:34:40.266  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-06-12 09:34:40.267  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-12 09:34:40.271  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-12 09:34:40.324  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-12 09:34:40.890  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2017-06-12 09:34:41.031  WARN 12880 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       : HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.planets.entity.AbstractPlanetoid
2017-06-12 09:34:41.186  WARN 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : create-update.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring
2017-06-12 09:34:41.604  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-12 09:34:41.930  WARN 12880 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playerRegistrationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registrationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.repository.PlayerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-06-12 09:34:41.931  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-12 09:34:41.944  INFO 12880 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-12 09:34:42.090 ERROR 12880 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field playerRepository in de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.service.RegistrationService required a bean of type 'de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.repository.PlayerRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.repository.PlayerRepository' in your configuration.
```

My SpringBootApplication:

```
package de.awesome.corporate.newworlds;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class NewWorldsApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(NewWorldsApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

My PlayerRepository:

```
package de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.entity.Player;

public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, String>{

    Player findByUserAccount(String useraccount);

}
```

The calling Service:

```
package de.awesome.corporate.newworlds.core.usermanagement.service;
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationCreationService organizationCreationService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
}
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.awesome.corporate.newworlds</groupId>
<artifactId>New-Worlds</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>new-worlds</name>
<description>Text-based Management Game</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT: It seems that, after removing spring-data-jpa-starter from the pom, and then reinsert it, that it also has problems now autowiring the password encorder.
Is there a general problem with the way spring does the autowiring?

Comment: Paste logs, POMs, etc., in the question itself.

Comment: Now,  why is my question being voted down?

Comment: Please don't let people click links to get a full picture. Add it to your question. Also I doubt that what you say is your pom is your actual pom file. Please add your **actual** pom file and not the **effective** pom.xml.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have addressed your feedback. However, I cannot post the whole log with spring debug on, as it exceeds the character limitations.

Comment: Am not seeing `@Query` annotation containg named query on  `Player findByUserAccount(String useraccount);` method in `PlayerRepository` interface. okay to have such abstract methods?

Comment: @harshavmb for JpaRepositories you can define the query by a specific syntax in the method name, look here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: oh.. great. Thanks! Just to be sure double check whether it is `findByUserAccount` or `findByUseraccount`. Thanks for sharing the doc. wasn't aware of such functionality!

Comment: @harshavmb It is, but if there was no such property, the compiler would have thrown an appropriate exception telling me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, somewhere in the project structure, there was a different version of the repository, and a different version of the player.

While usually I would expect Spring to produce an error telling me that there are multiple services with the same type description, I suspect due to both player and playerRepository being duplicates, this mechanism did not produce the expected error method, but instead told me that there is *no* service of that name at all.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar: I had more than one ORM class and more than one repository for the same entity, and that prevented the Application from running properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had repositories for both mongo and mysql database. so I was using spring data jdbc for mysql database and spring data mongodb for mongoDB. spring could not find jdbc repositories because when there is more then one datasource spring enters strict repository mode and if your entities are not properly annotated spring wont be able to identify the repos.
for example if you are using JPA, annotate your entities with @Entity.
sprinf-data-jdbc --> @Table, spring-data-mongodb --> @Document.